# How to create a pivot table that gives an average based on two factors, when you have duplicated entries with different data in one of the factors?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, data-analysis

I want a pivot table that gives me the average of entries per category, based on country.
e.g. I have a report with 100 entries, some of each have duplicated unique numbers because for each catergory there's a new entry. each unique number belows to a country.

A table as example:

[image: a table as example]

I have added the country as row, the category in columns and the unique number in values and changed the settings to deliver an average but it gives an error.